# C# Class for working with unknown objects

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to C# and have some trouble wrapping my head around a problem. I might be stuck in the mindset of my primary programming language.

We have a Web API solution where multiple SOAP services are added (and in the future new addition might be JSON REST). The problem is that they do not have the same function calls so I want to create a "Translation" layer that the API Controller code can talk to and the translation layer handles the differences.

So let's say for example:

- API: GET:/api/Users/company1 -> SOAP 1:
  SoapContext01Client.GetUsers()
- API: GET:/api/Users/company2 -> SOAP 2:
  SoapContext02Client.GetBrukere()

How would I go around creating something like:

- API: GET:/api/Users/companyX -> ProxyClass.GetUsers()
- Some logic to figure out what Soap/REST provider to use.
- Have a mapper or something that know what function I need to call on the Soap/Rest service as they might differ from system to system.

I've looked into Reflection, but cannot wrap my head arround it and if its something I can actually use.

I know that I should provide some code, but this is more a code-design question, but any code examples would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's what you're looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/87d83y5b.aspx.

Comment: I think Reflections is a good start for your problem but maybe (if i understand you correctly) you should take a look at runtime compiling too, if you want to call dynamic methods which are changing. But as the comment above mine mentions maybe its more trivial to use interfaces ;)

Comment: Thanks all. I've started looking into intefaces to see if I can get  it working. Coming from a loosely typed language its hard with all this Visual Studio(.NET) magic :-)